# Is there General Formula for an nth Order Central Finite Difference

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations, derivatives, reference-request, numerical-methods

I am searching for a general formula for directly calculating the second, fourth, and sixth derivative directly from a time series data. Wikipedia has a formula for finding an $n$th order central finite difference. I have searched a lot of places but I cannot find it in any reference book? The equation is given on a Wikipedia page under the section "Higher Order Difference."

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Finite_difference

Does anyone know a good reference where one can find a general formula for nth order finite difference?

Comment: You can find ["The Calculus of Observations"](https://archive.org/details/calculusofobserv031400mbp) by Whittaker and Robinson scanned oopy. Chapter III is Central DIfference Formulae  and the next Chapter IV is Applications of Difference Formulae. Page 64 and 65 is derivatives in terms of central differences.

Comment: Thank you for the link. I will check.

Comment: There's a paper by Fornberg 1988 titled "Generation of Finite Difference Formulas on Arbitrarily Spaced Grids" ... It's a good place to start. There is also an online calculator (http://web.media.mit.edu/~crtaylor/calculator.html) and I'm pretty sure they give you the code there if you want to implement it yourself

Answer (score 0):

Wikipedia articles come with extensive lists of references. Just picking one promising-looking reference at random (Calculus of Finite Differences by Jordan) I found a section on central differences including the general formulas for $n$th order central differences (they're written in terms of other formulas for forward differences, but putting the pieces together is straightfoward).

Comment: Thank you, I checked the first few reference books listed there, but none of them give the exactly show the same relationship as listed there. Also got hold of Jordan's book (1950). The notation is very different. It does not have the same formulae as given in Wikipedia under Higher Order Difference. I am searching this out of curiosity if any other book shows the same equations (written in similar modern notation as in Wikipedia). That section does not have any citation.

Comment: @M.Farooq I don't understand why you need the exact same notation. Surely you can change the notation yourself to suit your needs? Or just use the formula in Wikipedia?

Comment: Thanks, I just wanted to confirm if the nth order central difference formula in Wikipedia is correct. I am a chemist, trying to implement this in Excel to see higher order even derivatives of a chromatographic peak directly without all derivatives in series (1st, then, 2nd, 3rd and so on). This was the reason for searching a general relation to directly check 2nd, 4th, 6th etc.